# Use of bolding in a question

Tags: discussion, question-quality, markdown

I always used **bold** to highlight **key elements** in a text.

I didn't had any problem using it before on SO ([How to move changes without committing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706775/how-to-move-changes-without-committing), [Fit elements into box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790287/fit-elements-into-box), [Split 2D quad by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559015/split-2d-quad-by-line)), so I was a little concerned when [a question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501385/server-techology-for-inter-communicated-processes) was edited and stripped from all its formatting, with the editor stating that:

> This site is **not a chatroom** nor is it **correct form** to be using **bold all the time** because in **many ways** using **bold to make arbitrary points** is just as bad as **USING UPPERCASE** which many people equate with **SHOUTING**.

My answer is that it provides contrast to a block of text, for the same reason we use spacing, and for the same aesthetic reason we don't use Courier New when writing. I tried to find a FAQ regarding the *correct form of using bold*, but didn't find anything. Just this question: [How to handle user rollbacks due to stubbornness about formatting / content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256466/how-to-handle-user-rollbacks-due-to-stubbornness-about-formatting-content).

Why the editor removed all formatting on my text? Is this a common practice in SO? If so, why do we have *italics* and **bold** options?

Comment: I'd have to say I find the amount of bold in your post annoying.  Enough so I'd probably close your question without bothering to read it.  Bold should be like 1 or 2 words a post, max.

Comment: IMO, I see some abuse highlighting all "keywords" as many are not so "key" (http, ajax, php -these are all uppercase already, just like SO and FAQ here). But stripping everything was maybe an exageration from the editor.

Comment: @brasofilo, I understand the logic behind not using bold when a word is already uppercase, that's a good one. Thanks for that!

Comment: To put it bluntly, your posts are ugly. Very ugly. Worse, that level of highlighting makes them read like you are roughly ten years old and are putting extraordinary stress on one or two words in each sentence. Probably not the impression you want to give.

Comment: @dmckee - It reminds me of the text in a **Japanese video game**. _Yuck_

Comment: @dmckee, thanks for the honesty. Why is that putting emphasis on keywords makes it look like I'm ten years old? I reviewed some of your material and you have some [capitalization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273909/how-do-i-manipulate-path-elements-in-shell-scripts), [misspelling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436460/gdb-debugging-in-terminal-os-x-10-8-5-with-zsh/21168342#21168342) and [punctuation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735126/are-there-alternate-implementations-of-gnu-getline-interface) errors, so I'm sorry I can't take your appreciation in high regard.

Comment: @Veehmot - Because this is not the way typical adult documents are formatted.  This is formatting for kid's books, video games, menus, ads, badly designed web sites etc etc.  This kind of formatting does not convey a sense of seriousness, it is tricky and child-like.

Comment: @Hogan, thanks for the explanation. If you take the original question in SO, and you only take the bold words, you will get: "main process", "other processes", "HTTP", "AJAX", "database is not necessary", "technology", "PHP", "NodeJS". The intention is that someone reading over the line can get a grasp of what I'm asking for. I understand some concepts were incorrectly marked as important, and I agree with you at some point that documents are not formatted this way.

Comment: I'm also wondering why the downvotes on this question. This is not a matter of taste, it's a question about whether a format one doesn't like is enough reason for a high rep user to edit or even close the question, as @GabeSechan suggested. I understand some might not like another user format, but is it enough reason to edit the answer to our own taste or close it?

Comment: Posts to Stack Overflow are technical writing. Skimming them for keywords is a horrible way to try to understand them. If you want good answers your readers are going to have to read closely to be sure they know what you are and are not asking. Making selected words in the text grab for the attention detracts from paying proper attention to the rest of the communication. Good technical write should be as easy to read as possible. Not easy to skim, easy to read.

Comment: @Veehmot Sorry, I should have been more technical in my words on this site.  I probably wouldn't vote to close for that reason.  I might downvote.  I would close the tab without helping you (what I meant by close).

Comment: Votes on meta are often used to indicate disagreement with a post rather than to indicate perceived quality of the post. That is, people are voting on your idea. There has been a suggestion that people stop this except on feature-request posts, but it didn't stick.

Comment: I just had to edit this question to remove some of the formatting. It makes the question a little easier to read.

Comment: @JakeGould: Very funny, but that edit does not improve the question's quality... Quite the contrary.

Comment: @JakeGould: Oh, I **overlooked** the fact that your addition was a **comment**, not a entered **reason** with the edit. **My bad** ;-)

Comment: @Veehmot - There has not been a single poster on meta that has come out on "your side" of this issue and your question has not received a single up-vote.  Accept that you're view of "useful formatting" is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @Hogan, that was never in dispute. I would be a fool to try to convince other people that my formatting style is better than others. What is in dispute is if an user has the authority to change the style of an answer without even modifying the content, just because to his taste is isn't readable.

Comment: *"What is in dispute is if an user has the authority to change the style of an answer without even modifying the content"* No. It is not. On Stack Exchange sites other users can modify your posts. That is by design. The ability to improve posts--rather then adding a new one and letting the old ones molder--is one of the things that makes Stack Exchange work better than plain ole vanilla forums.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is nothing, in general, wrong with bolding things. However, used excessively, it can impair readability. Surely the degree to which it does for a given text varies from person to person, but while I probably wouldn’t have edited it out in this case, I do believe that the bolding was enough to impair the readability of the text.

When I bold things, I often do it for a few reasons:

- **Summary sentences in lists.** Like this. It functions as a miniature header, preparing the reader for what I am about to say in more detail. If, however, I’m not going to have any prose besides the header, it’s probably overkill.
- **Providing warnings.** Sometimes I might want to caution someone against the use of something:

  > If you really want to, you can kill a thread with `Thread.kill`. However, **I strongly advise against doing that,** for reasons X, Y, and Z.

…and perhaps some other reasons. (I partially wanted to use a list there just as an example.) What I don’t use it for is highlighting terms that fit some vague definition of importance. If there’s a sentence that’s important, I might bold it. If there’s a term that could easily be confused with some other term I just mentioned, I might bold (or italicize it). Bolding draws the eye, and where things need special attention, it’s a useful typographical tool. But bolding things just because they’re nouns is a distraction, drawing the eye when *all* the prose is important, and to me, having so much bolded just impairs readability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your time. I agree on your points. Maybe there should be a formatting style somewhere on SO.

Comment: @Veehmot http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers

Comment: One case where the bold is working well, is your Split 2D Quad question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559015/split-2d-quad-by-line Using it to emphasize the part of the result which changes is helpful.

Comment: @JakeGould you are exaggerating the original issue. I never wrote every other word in bold, and I never will. All I did was to highlight key concepts. Wikipedia has a [Manual of Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style), so if I'm going to get my answers edited by a random user who thinks the style is not good for him, I would like to get a style guide of what is good for the majority of users. As I said before, I always used this kind of bold and never had an issue in any document I wrote.

Comment: @JakeGould I understand the question was vague. I don't have an issue with that, as I understand the close reason. I opened a different post here on meta for specifically deal with the only issue I had, that is your edit of my style. I won't hold a tantrum just because my answer was closed, I have other plenty questions which were answered and upvoted. If I had an issue why my question being closed, this post would be titled something along the lines of "Why my question was closed?".

Answer (score 6):

As said in a comment by OP.

> I would be a fool to try to convince other people that my formatting
>   style is better than others. What is in dispute is if an user has the
>   authority to change the style of an answer without even modifying the
>   content, just because to his taste is isn't readable

Yes a user has the "authority" to change the style of answer.  You have seen indenting changes a 'zillion times if you have used SO at all.

**Let's be blunt:**  This isn't about a single user that disagrees with you, it is about a whole community that disagrees with you.  The point everyone is trying to make, that you can't see to understand, is your formatting is terrible.  There is no one that likes it and thinks it is useful.  With such a case of unanimity then yes a user can edit the formatting of a post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I saw a question with bad indenting, I would change it right away, and I have done that before, so I perfectly understand what you mean. I now see your point of view.