# Prevent Users from editing for upto an hour as an option when posting a question

Tags: feature-request, questions

I recently read this post here [Users stating that they do not want their posts to be edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367885/users-stating-that-they-do-not-want-their-posts-to-be-edited) Which describes a user who didn't want his post editing and would rather have people clarify in the comments. I was thinking that a few times I've gone to post a question and it's been edited by someone straight away for various reasons (normally spelling mistakes etc) but a couple of times I've posted and then wanted to expand the question, while someone edits in new requirements.

I want to make the proposal that providing you have a certain amount of rep (Maybe 500?) users can opt to have their question locked for edits for up to an hour while they figure out the question or update it through clarification.

I think it would also be fair to say gold badge would be allowed to circumvent this, but it would provide a period where users can grow there questions themselves without having to handle community modification for a small period. I think this buffer would hopefully introduce questions that are work in progress that would accept people asking for more info and directing it via the comments while allowing the author to handle there question till it's ready.

Ultimately I see this as a way to open up Q/A while introducing clarification that is less likely to end up in rollback wars from the onset of the question.

Comment: No, this'll only lead to abuse. I really don't see early editing as such a huge problem it needs to be solved with technology.

Comment: Could you expand this assertion into an answer? thanks for your input @MartijnPieters

Comment: That invites too much to use the site as a *dump idea, revisit later* the ultimate scratch-pad. What is wrong with preparing it off-site and then post to the best of our abilities

Comment: @rene Well preparing offsite is something that will still happen regardless, but a small buffer of time to work through early kinks before it's essentially made editable I think would be a benefit. Your right it doesn't happen to often but sometimes people will just completely modify a question so they can submit an answer that fits with the newly updated question. Even if the updates don't correlate with the actual question and the owner ends up either rolling back or changing completely.

Comment: I have only run into a handful of cases where both I and the OP were aggressively editing a post where we had to coordinate edits in the comments.

Comment: @lix: "*sometimes people will just completely modify a question so they can submit an answer that fits with the newly updated question*" I have been on this site for a very long time, and I have *never* seen that happen. I'm not saying that it can't or doesn't, but it's *certainly* not a sufficient problem that we need a feature for.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, @rene Your right aggressively going back and forth is rare. No arguments there, though It's happened a few times on new user posts I've seen.

Comment: Just to be clear, it is only an prevent edits lock, right? Not a stop voting lock? So I can still down vote work in progress posts?

Comment: @Blastfurnace not all work in progress answers are awful or unanswerable either. Sometimes users will add a ton of detail and will need to add more as time goes on even if the heart of the problem is already on display.

Comment: @rene Yes that is correct, just prevents lower rep users from modifying the question for a small amount of time voluntarily.

Comment: @lix: "*not all work in progress answers are awful or unanswerable either*" A WIP question is bad because it's incomplete. Otherwise, it would not be a WIP; either the detail being added is *important* or it isn't. We should always vote based on the content we actually see, not what we hope it might become.

Comment: @lix: "*Sometimes users will add a ton of detail and will need to add more as time goes on even if the heart of the problem is already on display.*" Which is fine. What isn't fine is posting a non-answer, then locking it and saying "hey, nobody touch this until I finish actually answering". Adding more detail and explanation is fine, but a partial answer helps nobody.

Comment: @NicolBolas I recently submitted a question that had the crux of the problem in there with code and it was a WIP as I was just throwing information down to try and increase the likelihood it could be answered, I think it's hard to umbrella all posts that could be considered WIP to be fundamentally unanswerable, though I suppose that's just my opinion.

Comment: @lix: "*it was a WIP as I was just throwing information down to try and increase the likelihood it could be answered*" WIP *on your own time*. Once it's on this site, it's *our time* you're wasting. I see nothing wrong with someone being able to edit your post while you try to ask a complete question, or downvoting it while it's incomplete. And throwing information at people rather than localizing it on your own time is not good behavior.

Comment: @NicolBolas My suggestion just adds some form of buffer time so that users (hell maybe without 500 rep this could work better, maybe new users?) have sometime to sort there own question out while letting people know it's essentially being 'finalised'.

Comment: @lix: Then why is it on the site? Our site is for "finalized" questions, not WIPs. We allow editing because people can make mistakes; it's not because we don't want people to put forth good-faith effort in completing their posts before making them.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sadly while that may be what is written all over the walls and sung from the highest rooftop is far from reality for a lot of people posting questions, I'm starting to think this would almost be useful for newer users most.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Well, we have that: it's called *deletion* ;).

Comment: @Blastfurnace I suppose that would make my feature request almost equivalent to a 'allow me to put this on hold' button from the onset.

Comment: am I the only one with that feature already? I leave my new question in my SO draft.... no one can edit it but me. When I am satisfied, I just post it. I don't see why it would make sense to change the workflow that way

Comment: Problem isn't too many edits, it is too few.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good question should not need significant editing by the author or another user.

A bad question should be edited to make it better, or closed. The sooner one of these things happen, the better, as less time will be wasted on bad questions.

The time before a question is posted is when the question should be thought out, not the hour after it is posted.

Answer (score 24):

No.

If you aren't done writing your question yet then *don't post it*.  Only post your question once you have finished writing it and no longer have any more changes that you want to make to it.  If you need to wait a little while after writing your draft to feel confident that you haven't forgotten anything then that's fine, take an hour (or however long you need) after writing your draft *before posting your question* to make sure it's as good of a question as you can make it.

Comment: That's some fair general advice and I agree with you, though it still won't stop people getting mad over edits or adding extra rubbish in that people have to clear up which is at the crux of my feature request.

Comment: @lix If the system doesn’t work when people use it the wrong way...why is that a problem?  This feature request tackles the symptom of people getting upset at editors, but the root problem is that those people are using the site incorrectly.  Do we really want to make that any *easier*?

Comment: @lix Yes, people will sometimes get made over edits.  That will still happen (after the time ends) even with your feature request, only now lots of people will be made that they (and others) can't edit posts to fix problem at first.  Likewise, people will still make bad edits.  The system is designed to handle bad edits though; they can be caught in review, or rolled back by others.  The only way to get rid of all edits is to remove the ability to edit.  But the good edits outnumber the bad edits; the system does more good than harm.